# how to instantiate webdriverio chromedriver in non-headless mode on Azure remote linux agent

Tags: typescript, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber, webdriver-io

Using typescript + cucumber + webdriverio for executing automated tests on remote linux agent. The code is working fine in headless mode on pipeline but getting error when removing the headless option from chromeOptions.

I am currently using '--headless' in webdriverio chromedriver chromeOptions and tests are executing in linux remote agent.

When trying to execute the tests in non-headless mode on linux remote agent getting error:
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:42947

Is there any installation needed to be done on linux remote agent before initiating the chromedriver? How this error can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Install the actual chrome browser on your server. Without headless mode, wdio is trying to launch the browser, but there is none.

But if you only have CLI access to your agent without remote desktop, there is no point of running without headless mode.

Comment: I will try the first point you mentioned. Thank you.. For second point you mentioned, in our pipeline CPU consumption is getting high when running tests in parallel. We are trying to use the non-headless chromedriver on same agent to compare the CPU consumption.